# How to enable Just In Time Debugger in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I haven't Just-In-Time in Options:
[image: Options]

I found to solve this with options of Internet :
[image: Internet Options]

But when I'm rebuilding solution I get this exception:
[image: Exception]

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How to enable Just In Time Debugger in Visual Studio 2017?

First, please make sure you have installed the component **Just-In-Time debugger** in the installer:

[image]

Then restart your Visual Studio, you will get that Just-In-Time in Options.

If you still have issue after install the component Just-In-Time debugger, you can try to update your Visual Studio to latest version.

Besides,

> This also could have happened when installing VS2017 on a machine that
>   once had a previous version of VS installed (the JIT debugger does not
>   uninstall with VS for backward compatibility reasons).
>
> To work around these issues until the fixes are released, run repair
>   to register the JIT debugger (assuming it was selected to be
>   installed) or uninstall and reinstall making sure to select the JIT
>   debugger.
>
> Once VS2017 is repaired/installed, start VS as administrator and go to
>   the JIT options page. Check all checkboxes and click OK.

Check the detail info from [Just-in-time debugging disabled and options missing](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/32571/just-in-time-debugging-disabled-and-options-missin.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: or if you use some other IDE like JetBrains Rider, then you also should check VS Build Tools update using VS Installer tool